# How to convert two variables added together to a label text using swift

Tags: ios, swift

For my own practice I have been trying to create app that adds adds two points to find the slope of a line (its also what I am doing in math class).  The part I am having trouble with is when I need to convert the int variables to the label text.  I am trying to add variables (x1point and x2point) to make the answer to that equal to (AnswerFinal).  After this the Answer text or where the answer is supposed to be will be Equal to the AnswerFinal value.  For example the if x1point value was 2 and x2point value was 3 then they would add together to make AnswerFinals value(5). T Now here is where the problem comes in when I try AnswerFinal value equal to the text of the Answer label.

Here is the error I am getting:

Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to type 'String!' in coercion

Here is all of my code for this viewcontroller:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {



    @IBOutlet var Answer: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var y2: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var x2: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var PointOne: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var PointTwo: UITextField!


    let y1 = 0

    let y2point = 0


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    @IBAction func SolveAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        solve()

    }
func solve()
{
     let x2point:Int?  = Int(PointOne.text!)
    let x1point:Int? = Int(x2.text!)

    let AnswerFinal: Int = x1point! + x2point!


    //Help pls

    Answer.text = AnswerFinal as String!

    }

}
```

Send me a message if you have a question I am young and new to all of this so take it easy on me thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either create a String from the `AnswerFinal`:

```
Answer.text = String(AnswerFinal)
```

or slightly more elegant and more variable using String interpolation:

```
Answer.text = "\(AnswerFinal)"
```

Comment: Ah thankyou for the answer will be sure to give you the answer check!